# How to add custom colors for social share icons in WordPress?

Tags: css, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm looking for solution to change my social share icon colors.
http://www.sourceone.lk/succeed-from-a-business-by-doing-what-you-love-and-loving-what-you-do/

Facebook
Twitter
Google +
LinkedIn

Can anyone have any suggestions pls?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this is the CSS you can use for that:

```
.themesflat-socials i { // for inner icon
    color: orange;
}

.themesflat-socials a { // for background color
    background: orange;
}
```

Second: There are attributes like: `:hover`, `:focus` for that please make yourself familiar with CSS.

Third: This doesn't have anything to do with WordPress at all it's simple CSS - sure the Theme is/was written for WordPress and therefor you're bound to that - but the change you're asking for is something your theme should be covering. The best place to ask questions for your Theme and how to change it according to your needs would be the place where you bought that theme from.

Comment: Yes. I have tried with Theme creator. But he's not responding. After adding that CSS it only change the color of the icon in middle. I want change the background colors of the icons.

Comment: Have a look at CSS in general. After you're familiar with that you can see that there is an attribute called background/background-color you can use for that. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Given that they're simply fonts, then you should be able to style them as fonts:

```
#elementID {
    color: #fff;

}
```

You can also just add style inline:

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook text-blue "></i>
```

`<i class="fa fa-facebook " style="color:#fff;"></i>`

You can see and learn more about look at  this   examples http://fontawesome.io/examples/